# ListView duplicate content after notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, listview

I'm designing a ListView powered by a custom adapter. In a fragment, i assign the adapter in onActivityCreated() like this :

```
private List<Datas> values = new ArrayList<Datas>();
private MyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    adapter = new MyAdapter(values, getActivity());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    .....}
```

Later in the app, i load datas from internet, and i put my values like this :

```
while(loop on every Datas items) {
    values.add(new Datas(...));
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChange();
```

When the user scrolls down, i load more items (thanks to an `OnScrollListener`, for the record), so the previous snippet is called again.
Basically, before update from scrolling, i have something like this : 
A, B, C, D, E, F.
After update, i have A, B, C, D E, F, A, B, C, D E, F, G, H, I, J, K ...

The first values appears twice, instate of just append at the end.

Thanks for reading and help :)

**Edit :** I re-considered my class, with a new adapter and everything. Now, without rational explanation, it works. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

that's because you are downloading already existing values and adding them again...
you should clear the list before adding, or (better) avoid downloading data that is already present in the list

Comment: Hi. No, i'm not, when i call my API i specify the last item on screen through it's ID, and the request give me the 20 next items. But that was also my first though, i had to double check that